# Does "long int num=24;" and "int num=24L;" do the same thing?

Tags: c

Do both declare & initiate a long integer?

I hope that's not too basic a question for this forum.I want to know if both the above statements achieve the same thing, ie declare a long integer variable num and initialize it to 24.Thanks.

Comment: they might create the same representation in memory... according to the standard this is not guaranteed because it depend on `long int` and `int` being the same (which is platform-dependent!).

Comment: @Yahia `long int` and `int` are never the same (though they may have the same representation and alignment requirements and ...).

Comment: @pmg you are right, that's what I meant... I changed my wording to reflect that...

Comment: I understood the core of the whole thing.But shall I also assume that the suffix "L" achieves  no purpose when used after a literal ?What exact purpose does this suffix serve then?

Comment: You can use `L` to avoid overflow, if your long is longer than an int.

Comment: @SheerFish Maybe you should ask that as a separate question (something like "In what scenario will adding a type suffix to an integer literal make a difference in C?").

Comment: @teppic You don't need the L suffix to avoid overflow in a constant. Integer constants that don't fit in an int, automatically have type long int.

Comment: @teppic If our long is longer than an int, then how does suffixing it with L avoid overflow?In that case is our variable "num" automatically converted to long?Please answer this!!

Comment: @sepp2k You just pinpointed what I intend to ask.So please tell me in a nutshell "In what scenario will adding L make a difference".

Comment: @SheerFish The type of a variable will never be anything other than the type it was declared as. What teppic meant was that you'd get an overflow if you initialized a long variable with an integer constant that doesn't fit into an int. He was wrong about that though.

Comment: @SheerFish As I said, that probably deserves to be its own question. Answering this here in a comment where no one else will ever see it, would be kind of a waste. (In other words: I want the rep). That is unless the question already exists, which I suppose it might.

Comment: @sepp2k OK Sepp, point noted.Actually I was apprehensive that it might be too trivial a question to ask.Now that you have said I can ask it, then I'll definitely do so once I go through all answers to this question.Thanks.

Comment: @sepp2k, not in an expression.

Comment: @teppic Integer constants that don't fit into an integer still have type long when used inside a larger expression. What you're thinking of is when both operands do fit it into an int, but the result does not.

Comment: @SheerFish, (INT_MAX + 1) is an overflow. (INT_MAX +1L) isn't, if your long is larger.

Comment: @sepp2k, yeah I know, I'm only talking about how it can avoid overflow in expressions, as in the example above.

Comment: @teppic Now I guess here's my embarrassing weakness I just found out---I had no idea about the concept of "Overflow in expressions".Till date,I only knew overflow as a situation when you assign a value to a variable which is more than what it can store.

Comment: @SheerFish - expressions have types too, and the calculation inside the expression must produce a value that's in range, or you get overflow. The example above forces both values to be long, giving a long result.

Comment: @teppic Clear this last thing for me brother,please---So the expression in the statement "int num= INT_MAX+1;" will face an overflow while the expression in the statement "int num=INT_MAX+1L;" wont' produce an overflow?Please, this much!It'll nail the whole thing for me.

Comment: @SheerFish: afraid not. INT_MAX + 1L is a long. It'd be fine to have `long num=INT_MAX + 1L`. A simple rule to remember is in assignment the right hand side must be converted to the type of the left hand side. In this instance the right hand side _doesn't_ overflow, but it won't fit in an `int`.

Comment: @SheerFish After a question on StackOverflow has been answered, you are expected to [accept the most deserving answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Doing so symbolically rewards the volunteers and keeps the site running. It also improves your own reputation in the eyes of future responders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `long int` declares a long int, and `int` declares an int variable. The type of the variable never depends on what value it is "initialized" with (more precisely, assigned to). Hence the two declarations are the same if and only if the types `long int` and `int` are the same in your environment.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't notice the suffix L after 24 in the second statement.

Comment: I did. But the suffix does not have any influence on the type of your variable.

Comment: If I assume "int num=24L" forces the system to store num in sizeof(long) number of bytes instead of size(int) number of bytes(say if they are different),then we will be using an integer pointer to dereference it or a long integer pointer?

Comment: Then John, what exactly does the suffix "L" do in that code ?

Comment: The question does not make sense, because your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Please rectify what's wrong with my assumption.That will help my understanding a lot.

Comment: It says that the constant on the right hand side is of type `long`. In the end, it does not do anything, as 24L is casted into an `int` immediately.

Comment: You write: If I assume "int num=24L" forces the system to store num in sizeof(long) number of bytes instead of size(int) number of bytes --- this is simply not true.

Comment: @SheerFish The suffix L changes the type of the value. That is 4L is a long int and 4 is an int. However it does not change the type of any variable that you put the value into. Putting a long int into an int variable, does not change the variable to be a long int -- it changes the value to be an int.

Answer (score 6):

> Are `long int num = 24;` and `int num = 24L` the same?

They're different.

The first "creates" a variable of type `long int` and implicitly converts the `int` value 24 to the `long int` type before assignment.
The second "creates" a variable of type `int` and implicitly converts the `long int` value 24 to the `int` type before assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. `long int` and `int` are not guaranteed, but supposed to be different sizes.

```
long int num = 24;
```

this is safe, as `24` is an int, that is (implicitly) promoted to `long int`.

```
int num = 24L;
```

this is not that safe IN GENERAL. `24L` defines a `long int`, that is "truncated" to `int` and if `sizeof(int)` < `sizeof(long int)` there COULD be a problem.

Why "IN GENERAL" and "COULD"? Because in this case, both things are the same and safe. But suppose do something like:

```
int num = xL;
```

where `x` is a large number, that can fit in `long int` but not in `int`? Then you have an overflow.

Comment: It may be better to say "truncated" instead of "sliced".

Comment: @jszakmeister - thanks, I know `sliced` was not the right word for this, that's why I put it in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

No. the type of the variable is defined by the type of the variable is defined by the type to its left only:

- `long int num` declares the variable `num` as a long int;
- `int num` declares the variable `num` as an int.

Meanwhile, the right hand side of the equals is also defined independently.

- `24` is an int;
- `24L` is a long int

The right hand side (in this case the `24` or `24L`) may then be forced (*ie* changed) to fit into the left hand side (in this case the variable `num`), but **never** the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to distinguish between the type of the variable and the type of the constant used to initialize the variable.

The first declaration declares a `long int` variable and initializes it to the value `24L` (which is what you get after casting the integer constant `24` to `long int`). The second declaration declares an `int` variable and initializes it to the value `24` (which is what you get after casting the long integer constant `24L` to `int`.)